# How do you Serialize an IEnumerable of a derived class in .net WebApi

Tags: asp.net, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am using the .net WebApi to create a web service and am having issues serializing a class to XML when one of the properties is an IEnumerable of a derived class.  I have tried adding the knownType bet get an error of:

> "Error   1   Attribute 'KnownType' is not valid on this declaration type.
>   It is only valid on 'class, struct' declarations."

JSON serialization works perfect but for XML I get:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Type 'test.order' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
</ExceptionMessage>
....
```

**Derived Classes example**

```
public class orderDetailBase
{
    public int sequence { get; set; }
    //.... more properties
}

public class onlineOrderDetail : orderDetailBase
{
    public string ip { get; set; }
    //.... more properties
}

public class inStoreOrderDetail : orderDetailBase
{
    public string storeAddress { get; set; }
    //.... more properties
}
```

**Class to serialzie**

```
public class order
{
    public int orderNumber{ get; set; }
    //..... more
    public IEnumerable<orderDetailBase> { get; set; }   // Serializing this causes issues
```

Any ideas how to get around this issues?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try modifying your 'orderDetailBase' class like below:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(onlineOrderDetail))]
[KnownType(typeof(inStoreOrderDetail))]
public class orderDetailBase
{
   [DataMember]
   public int sequence { get; set; }
```

Comment: I get an error when I try that.  Basically says knowtype can only be used for classes or struct.  Doesn't work for IEnumerable.

Comment: hmm...did you apply the KnownType attribute on the property IEnumerable<orderDetailBase>?...if so, remove it and try again...

Comment: You were right I had it in the wrong place.  I can see the xml now, but instead of the data I get the following for my 4 details


<d4p1:orderDetailBase i:type="d4p1:onlineOrderDetail"/>
<d4p1:orderDetailBase i:type="d4p1:onlineOrderDetail"/>
<d4p1:orderDetailBase i:type="d4p1:onlineOrderDetail"/>
<d4p1:orderDetailBase i:type="d4p1:onlineOrderDetail"/>

Comment: i updated my above post. since the class has been decorated with datacontract attribute, we need to decorate it with datamember attribute (ex: sequence property above)...irrespective of that the property 'ip' should have been serialized...do you actually have an 'ip' property or was is it just for this forum post...

Comment: Thanks, DataMember did the trick!  IP was just for this post :)